# can we integrate a processing gui with moodle?

Tags: user-interface, processing, moodle, integrate

i made a gui recently where the goal was to view the results of some actions there , so mostly it was like a simulation game that has no connection with any hardware , i proposed this for my school that uses moodle and i want to know if there is a way to integrate it there , the gui i used has controlP5 library and videos and gif libraries as well, i would appreciate the help

from my researches so far i found that we can integrate processing code with html after some modifications , but didn't find anything for moodle yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that Processing in java mode, using controlP5, etc. will work on a client machine, not on a server (like moodle) (not easily at least).

Regarding embedding a processing sketch a web page:

- java applet support is deprecated (can no longer embed a .jar applet)
- processing.js is deprecated (and controlP5 wouldn't be compatible anyway)
- you can however port your code to [p5.js](https://p5js.org/get-started/)

I don't know enough moodle, but perhaps you can embed a JS snippet/[iframe](https://docs.moodle.org/310/en/Iframe)/etc on a moodle page.

Regarding controlP5, in p5.js, you can look at p5.dom.js functionalities such as [`createSlider()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/createSlider), [`createButton()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/createButton), etc. or use libraries like [p5.gui](https://github.com/bitcraftlab/p5.gui) or [p5.touchgui](https://github.com/L05/p5.touchgui).

Comment: i was looking online and yes that's exactly what i found , it seems the only way is to rewrite the program with the p5 language and add it in the Moodle html code since it supports it and replace the controlp5 with something similar in the other language . thank you for your answer you confirmed my doubts and saved me hours of searching